# How to auto sort simple products by Price attribute on Configurable product?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, sorting, simple-product

So I have a configurable product which pulls certain attributes from the simple product using this code:

```
if($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable"):
$conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product);
$simple_collection = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
foreach($simple_collection as $simple_product){
    echo $simple_product->getSku() . " - " . $simple_product->getName() . " - " . Mage::helper('core')->currency($simple_product->getPrice()) . "<br>";
}
```

This works perfectly.

What I want it to do now is sort the products by price, with the lowest at the top.

I am a noob, so if anyone can help me with it and modify the code for my needs, you will be a life saver :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following should do the trick:

```
->addFinalPrice()
```

and

```
->order('price_index.final_price', 'asc')
```

The line will look like following:

```
$simple_collection = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions()->addFinalPrice()->order('price_index.final_price', 'asc');
```

I assume "lowest at the top" means "lowest first"?
If the order does not fit, use 'desc' instead of 'asc'

**Edit:**

My bad, the 'order' function does not exists on this class.

Therefore it should be:

```
->addAttributeToSort('price_index.final_price', 'asc')
```

Also i saw that you just fetch the price. But when there is a sale, you will not show the different price there. I recommend you use the `$_product->getFinalPrice()` function.

But try the following instead of the above solution:

```
$conf->getUsedProductCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addFilterByRequiredOptions()
                ->addFinalPrice()
                ->addAttributeToSort('price_index.final_price', 'asc');
```

To display prices i recommend:

```
Mage::helper('core')->currency($simple_product->getFinalPrice())
```

Comment: Sorry, yes, lowest price first. Unfortunately this didnt work, just broke the page :(

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: Still didn't work. Didn't break the page though.

Comment: I kept the price as it was because the price actually gets updated from another website and will never have a sale value.

I added the code which you provided but used the simple price attribute

    ->addAttributeToSort('Price', 'asc')

Thanks a lot for your help :)